# Encrypting using Crypto in Node js throw error

Tags: node.js, express, encryption, node-crypto

I am trying to encrypt Credit Card data of customer to AES 256 CBC format but anytime I I call the API I get this error:

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:259:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:250:8)
```

This is my code for the encryption:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const encryptionType = 'aes-256-cbc';
const encryptionEncoding = 'base64';
const bufferEncryption = 'utf8';
export class AesEncryption {
   

  AesKey: string;
  AesIV: string;
  init() {
    this.AesKey = process.env.SECRET as string;
    this.AesIV = process.env.SECRET?.slice(0, 16) as string;
  } 

 
    encrypt(jsonObject: Object): string {
        const val = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
        const key = Buffer.from(this.AesKey, bufferEncryption);
        const iv = Buffer.from(this.AesIV, bufferEncryption);
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(encryptionType, key, iv);
        let encrypted = cipher.update(val, bufferEncryption, encryptionEncoding);
        encrypted += cipher.final(encryptionEncoding);
        return encrypted;
      }

    
}
```

This is the code of where I am using it:

```
public async createPayment(data: IPaymentDetails): Promise<IPaymentDetails> {
    try {
      PaymentService.checkPaymentRequiredFields(data);
      data.encryptedData = new AesEncryption().encrypt(data.card)
      console.log(data.encryptedData)
     ...
headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Cookie: 'PHPSESSID=7hnkto3se3mlsbnht755ok2ak6',
                  },
                  data: JSON.stringify({
                    merchantId: data.merchantId,
                    method: 'Card',
                    id: data.trans_id,
                    encryptedData: data.encryptedData,
                  }),
                })
```

Anytime I call the API I get the above error.

Comment: I don't think the encryption itself is the problem (at least not when using valid data). This part looks OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the key and iv from process.env is not updating correctly, so it was throwing undefined.

I have to pass the process.env.SECRET directly into the function instead of passing them inside a variable.

It worked.